# Using gets() gives "No such file or directory" error when I pass arguments to my script

Tags: ruby

Hi I am making a simple ruby script practiced where I make a form using `gets.chomp` and arguments, the problem is that when `gets.chomp` use the script returns me an error when I apply the argument `test`.

The code:

```
#!usr/bin/ruby

def formulario(quien)
    while (1)
        print "[+] Word : "
        word = gets.chomp
        print quien + " -> " + word
    end
end

quien = ARGV[0]

formulario(quien)
```

The error:

```
[+] Word : C:/Users/test/test.rb:8:in `gets': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - test (Errno::E
NOENT)
        from C:/Users/test/test.rb:8:in `gets'
        from C:/Users/test/test.rb:8:in `formulario'
        from C:/Users/test/test.rb:17:in `<main>'
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but `#!usr/bin/ruby` is missing a leading `/`; it should be `#!/usr/bin/ruby` ... This is only required for UNIX & UNIX-like systems, though, and isn't really used on Windows (except for CygWin).

Answer (score 115, accepted):

It looks like you want to the user to type some input by reading a line from `STDIN`, the best way to do this is by calling `STDIN.gets` and not `gets`. So your line becomes:

```
word = STDIN.gets.chomp
```

This is documented as [`IO.gets`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/IO.html#method-i-gets). `STDIN` is an instance of `IO`.

Right now, you're executing [`Kernel.gets`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Kernel.html#method-i-gets), which does something different (emphasis mine):

> Returns (and assigns to $_) the next line from the **list of files in ARGV** (or $*), or **from standard input if no files are present** on the command line.

This *appears* to behave like `STDIN.gets` if `ARGV` is empty, but is not the same thing, hence the confusion.

Comment: [`gets` defaults to being read from STDIN](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Kernel.html#method-i-gets), so `STDIN.gets` isn't necessary.

Comment: @theTinMan I had the exact same error and specifying `STDIN` worked for me.

Comment: I can confirm that using STDIN.gets instead solved this same issue for me too.

Comment: Thanks. Unexpected convenience can lead to strange places. I think this behavior is bizarre, but if I was used to it I might find it handy instead.

Comment: weird, i didn't know `ARGV` interfered with `.gets`; this answer worked for me too

Comment: The point being that if you run your program with command line arguments, you need to specify`STDIN`.

Answer (score 0):

If your program handle empty argument nor non-empty argument. You can use this module (especially if you already use default `gets` everywhere)

```
# A module that help to use method gets no matter what the file argument is
module InputHelper
    # Handle input method based on its file argument
    def gets
        if ARGV.nil?
            Kernel.gets
        else
            STDIN.gets
        end
    end
end
```

and then you could include it on your class

```
require 'input_helper'
class YourClass
    ...
    include InputHelper
    ...
end
```

Comment: There is an error in this module. ARGV, when no arguments are supplied, is an empty array, [], and will never be nil, therefore the conditional will always be false and always execute STDIN.gets

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue today in Ruby 3.1.2. I can also confirm that STDIN.gets avoids this problem. An alternative workaround is to set ARGV to an empty array prior to capturing input via gets. You can simply set

```
ARGV = []
gets.chomp # works fine here
```

or store them elsewhere if you must get input before you've dealt with them all

```
cli_args = ARGV.dup
ARGV.clear
gets.chomp # works fine here
```